# What is the effect of every button in the Gauntlet Bridge Puzzle of Dragon Age:Origins?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

In **Dragon Age**, there is a mini-game related to the quest for retrieving the Sacred Urn of Andraste's Ashes from an ancient temple.

The mini-game is known online as *Gauntlet Bridge Puzzle*, and it looks like this:

[image: Gauntlet Bridge Puzzle Solution]

There exist plenty of sources which provide the *solution* for this mini-game.

Instead, I would like to know what is the effect of pressing each button individually, assuming a naming convention as follows:

```
  EXIT
L6    R6
L5    R5
L4 B4 R4
L3 B2 R3
L2 B2 R2
L1 B1 R1
  START
```

**e.g.** by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIVejv9sHLg), I was able to deduce that `R2` semi-activates `B1` and `B2`. Unfortunately, not all buttons are being pressed in this video so it is hard to reconstruct the whole situation from it.

Can anyone playing this game help?

*(note: I am currently unable to play this game)*